# Reload page once after it's fully loaded with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like that page is reloaded ONLY once, with jquery, but only if on page is specific form with unique ID, is that possible even?

Thanks!

Comment: It should be possible, but I really have to ask: Why?

Comment: This is such an odd request that it would be better if we could help you with what problem you are really trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done:

1. Add a script to the `$(document).ready` to check for your form / "magic" ID
2. If the condition is true check if `document.referrer` isn't yourself
3. If so, reload.

Comment: can you help me out with actualy example?